# Recebendo e-mails em branco com o PHP

Tags: php, html, email

Eu criei um formulário para que usuários pudessem me contatar através do site, porém, quando os dados do formulário são preenchidos e enviados, o e-mail chega em branco e de um e-mail chamado postmaster.
Apesar de minhas tentativas de mudar variáveis e afins, as informações que as pessoas preenchem, nunca aparecem, apenas o mesmo e-mail em branco com uma pequena frase que eu coloquei para saber de quem vinha o e-mail.

Trecho do HTML em que inicio a form.

```html
<section class="section section-icons grey lighten-4 center">
  <div class="col s12 m6">
    <div class="card-panel white -3">
      <i class="material-icons medium blue-text">mail</i>
      <h4>Preencha os campos abaixo para entrar em contato conosco</h4>
      <form class="contact-form" action="form.php" method="post">

        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome">

        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">

        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Assunto">

        <input textarea name="message" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>

        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-large blue darken-3">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col s12 center">
      <a href="#top" class="btn btn-small blue darken-3">
        <i class="material-icons left">arrow_upward</i> Retornar ao topo
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

PHP que tenho tentado utilizar:

```html
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 $mailFrom = $_POST['mail'];
 $subject = $_POST['subject'];
 $message = $_POST['message'];
 
 $mailTo = "contato@liderdp.com.br";
 $headers = "From: ".$mailFrom;
 $txt = "Foi recebida uma nova mensagem de:"$name.".\n\n".$message;
 
 mail($mailTo, $subject, $txt, $headers);
 header("Location: index.html?emailenviado");
}

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

olá, tente algo assim:

```
<form class="contact-form" action="form.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Nome">
        <input type="email" name="mail" placeholder="E-mail">
        <input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Assunto">
        <input textarea name="message" placeholder="Mensagem"></textarea>
        <button type="submit" name="submit" class="btn-large blue darken-3">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Aqui está o form.php

```
    <?php
  //1 – Definimos Para quem vai ser enviado o email
  $para = "meu@email.com.br";

  //2 - resgatar o nome digitado no formulário e  grava na variavel $nome
  $name = $_POST['name'];

  // 3 - resgatar o assunto digitado no formulário e  grava na variavel //$assunto
  $assunto = $_POST['assunto'];

  $mail = $_POST['mail'];

  $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];

  $escola = $_POST['escola'];

  $msg = $POST['contato'];


   //4 – Agora definimos a  mensagem que vai ser enviado no e-mail
  $mensagem = "<strong>Nome:  </strong>".$name;

  $mensagem .= "<br>  <strong>Email: </strong>".$_POST['mail'];

  $mensagem .= "<br>  <strong>assunto: </strong>".$_POST['assunto'];

  $mensagem .= "<br>  <strong>Mensagem: </strong>".$_POST['message'];

  $mensagem .= "<br> <strong>Promoção/interesse: Educação infantil</strong>".$_POST['msg'];



//5 – agora inserimos as codificações corretas e  tudo mais.
  $headers =  "Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8\n";

  $headers .= "From:  seudominio.com.br<meu@email.com.br>\n"; //Vai ser //mostrado que  o email partiu deste email e seguido do nome

  $headers .= "X-Sender:  <meu@email.com.br>\n"; //email do servidor //que enviou

  $headers .= "X-Mailer: PHP  v".phpversion()."\n";

  $headers .= "X-IP:  ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";

  $headers .= "Return-Path:  <meu@email.com.br>\n"; //caso a msg //seja respondida vai para  este email.

  $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";

mail($para, $assunto, $mensagem, $headers);  //função que faz o envio do email.


?>
```